# How to drop tcp / udp connection using code?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, tcp, udp

I am currently using .net core and would like to be able to drop some tcp and/or udp connections that are open on the host machine.

I have already built all the logic for checking the open connections and I am now just needing to find some resource that will help me drop the connection on the machine.

With windows I can use a third party program passing some parameters during initialization. However I need it to work on a linux machine.

Windows Solution = http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

Comment: Connections are dropped if the connected processes are killed.

Answer (score 0):

Network connections are a very common example of unmanaged Resources, that need to be [disposed off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). A big reason we Dipose of SQL Connections, is because of the underlying network connection.

When dealing with disposeable classes my advise is: "Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)."

Note that with Networking you usually have to apply some form of Multitasking. Async/Await is the more modern approach, but a seperate thread can also be used. That prevents the UI thread from being blocked, while still making sure the using is not split up logically - and thus stays reliable.

Comment: Hello Christopher. I understand. However the connections are not made by me. Are third party to my server. And I would like to close these connections as I am suffering from malicious connection issues.

Comment: @GustavoFonseca My one answer for that is: **Don't!** Going around and closing random network connections of other programms on the OS? That is Virus behavior! Maybe if that was the only purpose of a programm designed to do network admin support - it would still be sketchy as heck, but at least be on thematic.